# Javascript for loop stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

Basically what I'm trying to do is traverse a pretty big (>2k lines) table, and get some information out of it with a javascript for loop.
The first iteration is doing exactly what I want, but that's it. It doesn't do anything else but return the first line and stops.

There is no error, and I'm at a loss after searching what could be the problem for several hours.

This is the script:

```
function start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i];

        var date = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML;
        var btime = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML;
        var etime = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[3].innerHTML;
        var name = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[5].innerHTML;
        var loc = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[8].innerHTML;

        document.write(date + " " + name + " at " + loc + " from " + btime + " - " + etime);
    }
    document.write("End");
}
```

And what is returned is the following:

```
05-09-2011 Intro Module, Intro AI at AMC K01-222
from 10:00 - 12:00
```

And an example of the first table:

```
<table class="TableBody">
    <tr>
      <td class="dayCol">Ma</td>
      <td class="typeCol">05-09-2011</td>
      <td class="startCol">10:00</td>

      <td class="endCol">12:00</td>
      <td class="nameCol">3.1 Artificiële Intelligentie</td>
      <td class="nameCol">Intro Module, Intro AI</td>
      <td class="typeCol">H</td>
      <td class="staffCol">dr. D. Sent<br></td>
      <td class="roomCol"><a href="http://rooster.uva.nl/current_nl/showtimetable.aspx?type=reporturl&amp;idstring=830K01222">AMC K01-222</a><br></td>

      <td class="commentCol"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dayCol">Ma</td>
      <td class="typeCol">05-09-2011</td>
      <td class="startCol">12:45</td>
      <td class="endCol">16:45</td>

      <td class="nameCol">3.1 Artificiële Intelligentie</td>
      <td class="nameCol">Zoeken</td>
      <td class="typeCol">H</td>
      <td class="staffCol">dr. N.B. Peek<br></td>
      <td class="roomCol"><a href="http://rooster.uva.nl/current_nl/showtimetable.aspx?type=reporturl&amp;idstring=830K01222">AMC K01-222</a><br></td>
      <td class="commentCol"> </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

So the first TR block is doing exactly as expected, but it isn't going to the second block and further (using the **i** variable from the loop.

If I up the **i** variable in the third line manually, it does show the information of the TR block from put in number (e.g. if I change **i** to 15, it shows the 15th block info).

So I really don't know what's going wrong here. I would love if another pair of eyes could see what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `document.write` which clears table so in the next iteration `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')` returns nothing.

Instead of writing to the document using `document.write` you can append it into a dom element. Take a look at this.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezbaX/)**

Comment: Excellent! That sounds pretty logical too, wouldn't have searched in that direction at all. Thanks, big help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `document.write`, which will replace the current document with what you write out. So, when you get to the second iteration in the loop, the table doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `var tr =` outside the loop, plus the issue with `document.write` as pointed out by others.

```
function start() {
    var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
        var date = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML;
        var btime = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML;
        var etime = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[3].innerHTML;
        var name = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[5].innerHTML;
        var loc = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[8].innerHTML;

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = date + " " + name + " at " + loc + " from " + btime + " - " + etime;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    var end = document.createElement('div');
    end.innerHTML = "END";
    document.body.appendChild(end);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/hxpZn/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
function start() {
    var alltrs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        var tr = alltrs[i];

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a slight modification. It is in fiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/nwnSz/. This assigns the table to a variable, so that document.write won't clear it.